# How do you prevent a new window from opening when running :make

Tags: quickfix, make

Whenever I run `:make` in Vim, it always takes control away from my buffer, places me in a temporary view where I see the makeprg's output and then prompts me to "Press ENTER or type command to continue". Is there a way so I can run `:make` without leaving my current buffer?

For context, I'm using pyunit to parse Python tracebacks, using make. WHen make is finished, it populates the traceback in my quickfix buffer. So I don't need to see the intermediary make output. Just the quickfix is all I want.

For context, I'm running something like this:

```
compiler pyunit
set makeprg=cat\ %
make
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this natively in vim is to utilise `system()` or `systemlist()`.  I'm not familiar with pyunit, but something like the following may help you get started.

```
function! MyMake() abort
    let l:efm = "%C %.%#,%A  File "%f"\, line %l%.%#,%Z%[%^ ]%\@=%m"
    let l:lines = systemlist("cat " . expand("%"))
    call setqflist([], " ", {"efm": l:efm, "lines": l:lines})
endfunction
```

Comment: This got me really close but `l:efm` only matches a single line. It doesn't create individual entries for each function call. I went with `let l:efm = '%A  File "%f"\, line %l\, in %o,%C    %m,%Z'` and it works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tpope’s [dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin and run `:Make` for an asynchronous make.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't work the same. Though I do use that plugin for other types of projects.

Comment: @ColinKennedy Can you expand on how it doesn't work the same? Which part of it doesn't work for you?